# IBM Worklight 5.0 - White spacing at the bottom of the application

Tags: android, css, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to make a simple app using worklight 5.0.
Here is a screenshot of my app on my device:

[image]

The problem is almost negligible, but i want to fix this.

It is not easily visible in the screen shot so you need to hold & drag it. You will notice white spacing below the tabbar.

In my CSS I have already defined the height to be 100% but still this 10-20px margin is there at the bottom.

Below are my,

CSS:

```
#content{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 49%, #2989d8 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799),
color-stop(49%,#7db9e8), color-stop(100%,#2989d8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 49%,#2989d8 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 49%,#2989d8 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 49%,#2989d8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 49%,#2989d8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#2989d8',GradientType=0 ); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<body id="content">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="oneTwoTest"
    data-dojo-props="selected:true" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'HTML'"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="aboutView"
        data-dojo-props="scrollDir:'v'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane" id="aboutViewContentPane" href="pages/about.html" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is actually a screenshot of my android phone, the problem is that i don't see anything on the bottom of my screen, its just blank

Comment: your provided code does not show how you create the tabbar... Where is it? is it in about.html? this may explain the spacing below the tabbar in your image; the tabbar should be in the main view.

Comment: see my answer. Can this question be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Worklight 6.1, I have created a simple Dojo app with a fixed header and navbar.
When previewing:

- In Eclipse, I can see this white spacing below the navbar (see my comment to the question why this may happen in your version of the app)
- In Worklight Console's MBS or in an Android Emulator/device (running Android 4.4.2), the white spacing is not visible.

I am not convinced there is an error here.

Dojo-related contents of the `body` tag in index.html:
[Download sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsilq8pbgfl21zd/dojo_no_white_spacing.zip)

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props="label:'Heading'" fixed="top">
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view1" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
        test
    </div>

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" fixed="bottom" data-dojo-props="barType:'tabBar'">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton">Label</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton">Label</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton">Label</li>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton">Label</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Inside the RPE in Worklight Studio:**
[image]

**In Worklight Console's MBS:**
[image]

**In a Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.x) device:**
[image]